# What's the code for the "/" in the URL

Tags: html

The blank  is `%20` in the URL.

E.g. I put `http://www.testme.com/a test` in the URL field of browser.

The press "Enter" key, the URL will become `http://www.testme.com/a%20test`

So, does anyone know what's the code for the `/` in the URL as well?

Comment: You couldn't use google for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is : `%2F`

You can find out by using a url encoder/decoder like this one : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Answer (score 1):

here is the answer

```
From Windows-1252 : %2F

From UTF-8  :   %2F
```

Here is the full list of Encoder list FYI

[Encoder/Decoder List](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp)